# get a dimensional array from n lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm trying to get my predictions from my x_test data of one svm classifier:

```
maduros = []
ma_predecido = []

pintones = []
pi_predecido = []

verdes = []
ve_predecido = []
print("[INFO] Realizando clasificaciones de en los ejemplos de test (20%)")
for i in range(len(x_test)):
    #Predecir la clase para la imágen actual
    prediccion = svm.predict([x_test[i]])
    if y_test[i] == 0: #Maduro class
        maduros.append(0) #save the class
        ma_predecido.append(int(prediccion)) #save his output
    if y_test[i] == 1: #Pintones class
        pintones.append(1)
        pi_predecido.append(int(prediccion))
    if y_test[i] == 2: #Verdes class
        verdes.append(2)
        ve_predecido.append(int(prediccion))
#Concatenate the lists in an array
test_results = np.array(np.concatenate([maduros, ma_predecido, pintones, pi_predecido, verdes, ve_predecido]))

df = pd.DataFrame(test_results)
filepath = args["salida"]+str('/pruebas_test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
```

i.g maduros[] list is the name of clase and ma_predecido[] will save the outputs for this class.

My classes are:

```
"Maduro" one-hot encode = 0
"Pinton"  one-hot encode = 1
"Verde  one-hot encode = 2
```

Anyways my code is giving me a one dimensional array, i could check it in the file .xlsx that i got using pandas library:
[image: 1-d array]

I wanto get something like this:
[image: 2d array]

My goal is try to make a confusion matrix from scratch, I would like compare my results with the sklearn confusion matrix o pycm. By the moment i would like to save the class and his result (TP/FP).. I would like improve it:

```
 test_results = np.array(np.concatenate([maduros, ma_predecido, pintones, pi_predecido, verdes, ve_predecido]))
```

to get a 2d array like the last picture.
thanks

This is my confusion matrix:

```
[[74  2  0]
 [ 1 64  1]
 [ 0  0 68]]
```

According to pycm:

```
TPR(Sensitivity)         0.97368       0.9697        1.0
TNR(Specificity)                            0.99254       0.98611       0.99296
ACC(Accuracy)   0.98571       0.98095       0.99524
PPV(Precision or positive predictive value)  0.98667       0.9697        0.98551
```

[image: Cmatrix image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct your confusion matrix using numpy functions : np.where to find where you predicted a label and then to know where you were right. It could look like something like that :

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy
y_test = np.array([0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2])
y_pred = np.array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2])

# Expected output is the scikit learn confusion matrix
sk_cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Out :

```
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

Now we construct our own confusion matrix :

```
confusion_matrix = []
precision = []
succ_pred = 0
nmb = 0
TP = []
FN = []
for i in range(3):
    indices = np.where(y_test == i)
    new_row = []
    # Rows where we predicted 0
    new_row.append(len(np.where(y_pred[indices] == 0)[0]))
    # Rows where we predicted 1
    new_row.append(len(np.where(y_pred[indices] == 1)[0]))
    # Rows where we predicted 2
    new_row.append(len(np.where(y_pred[indices] == 2)[0]))
    precision.append(new_row[i]/np.sum(new_row))
    succ_pred += new_row[i]
    TP.append(new_row[i])
    FN.append(np.sum(new_row)-new_row[i])
    nmb += np.sum(new_row)
    confusion_matrix.append(new_row)
accuracy = succ_pred/nmb
```

Output :

```
[[3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3]]
```

Finally you can put this array in a df and save it to excel :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0' : confusion_matrix[0], '1' :confusion_matrix[1], '2': confusion_matrix[2]})
df.to_excel('test.xls')
```

Comment: thanks, i do something like that before, but i can't understant where on these confusion matrix are the FP, FN.. The diagonal could I know that are the TF.. I I used pycm to get my confusion matrix.. but I need to compute the sensibility, specificity, accuracy and precision from scratch.. it could be difficult? it is a multiclass problem, you recomend that is better to get the results from the library?.. what is your opinion.. thanks

Comment: I edited to compute the precision of each class @FreddyDaniel

Comment: Just added the accuracy too

Comment: yeah yeah.. thanks victor I hope that you arrive also to the recall and the specificity

Comment: I will left my confusion matrix and I will compare it with pycm according your code

Comment: You have to consider the FP as the elements not in the diagonal (like you said in your first comment). I edited a bit my code to compute them so you can have a better idea of how to compute them

Comment: I left my confusion matrix.

Comment: Ok now I understand those values out of the diagonal are the FP but what about the FN? Sensibility/recall requires it and the equation is: recall =  TP/(TP+FN)  100%

Comment: What do you think about the results of pycm? how you see the results? from my little knowledge .. the sensibility and the accuracy are a litttle balanced? thats right? I'm getting much TP with recall, i tested the svm and is clasifying well

Comment: If you want to gave all your recalls, precisions, f1_score etc.. you can always use the [calssification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) from scikit-learn metrics

Comment: do you think that do it with multple classes is complicate? my professor say to me tryed to get the outputs from the x_test data to then build the confusion matrix, but after export to excel one class is unbalanced, not all the classes has the same lenght respecto his output.

Comment: But to go back to the FN and FP. The FP are : sum of the column - diagonal_value and FN are sum of the line - diagonal value

Comment: Multi class classification is a bit harder than binary but you can definitely compute all the different metrics. As I said before the simplest way is to use the classification_report function which does all the job for you

Comment: classification report give:  precision,    recall,  f1-score and   support.. I need also specificity and accuracy.. do you think that with precision and recall is enough? the specificity always will be hight according with the number of samples..

Comment: My confusion matrix: [[74  2  0]
 [ 1 64  1]
 [ 0  0 68]] what happen here? my x_train was 80% from 1050 images, and the x_test data is 210 features, for 3 classes.. every set should be 70 features per class to test it.. but in the first row of my cmatrix I get 74 TP? what happend here..thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194221/discussion-between-vlemaistre-and-freddy-daniel).